# Cannot use MUI 'ContentCopy' icon

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to use the icon 'ContentCopy' from MUI.

https://mui.com/components/material-icons/ says to use the following import:

```
import ContentCopyIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ContentCopy';
```

No matter what I do, I get the error:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve '@mui/icons-material/
```

I have already tried the following:

```
npm install @material-ui/core
npm install @material-ui/icons
```

I also tried deleting my node-modules and re-running npm install.

Any ideas on what else I could try??

Comment: Looks like you're installing "material-ui" and trying to use "mui"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you confused of using version 4 and 5.

You need to install the icons of version 5.

```
npm install @mui/icons-material
```

And import the icon from the module.

```
import ContentCopyIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ContentCopy';
```

Please refer to [this](https://mui.com/getting-started/installation/#svg-icons).

Comment: @neel I think you forgot to check my answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

to version 5 you need to install mui

```
npm install @mui/icons-material
```

mui contains all the icons

```
from '@mui/icons-material/_';
```

info https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mui/icons-material